# what exactly is the moduli functor for classifying elliptic curves with (full) level N structure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, nt.number-theory, stacks, coarse-moduli-spaces

So, when people say, "the moduli problem of classifying elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ with level $N$ structure", there are usually two associated functors I've seen:

1. $P_N : \textbf{Ell}\rightarrow\textbf{Sets}$, where $\textbf{Ell}$ is the category of elliptic curves $E\rightarrow S$ over $S$ and morphisms are cartesian squares, and

   $P_N(E/S) = \text{set of isomorphisms } \alpha : E[N]\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2 \text{ of determinant 1}$
2. $F_N : \textbf{Sch}\rightarrow\textbf{Sets}$, where

   $F_N(S) = \text{set of isomorphism classes of pairs } (E/S,\alpha) \text{ with } \alpha\in P_N(E/S) $

I apologize for the length of this post, but this has been terribly confusing for me.

Alright, so I know that for $N\ge 3$, *both* functors are representable by the modular scheme $Y(N) := \Gamma(N)\backslash\mathcal{H}$ which are fine moduli schemes, and that's got something to do with the fact that there are no automorphisms of elliptic curves $E/S$ fixing any $\alpha\in P_N(E/S)$.

However, in the case $N = 1,2$, the modular curve $Y(2) := \Gamma(2)\backslash\mathcal{H}$ only gives you a coarse moduli scheme.

How should I think of the relation between the two above functors? In a way, a representing object $E/S$ for $P_N$ gives you both the universal elliptic curve $E$ and the base moduli scheme $S$ in one fell swoop. However, the functor $P_N$ doesn't seem like a naturally phrased moduli problem, since being able to represent $P_N$ just says:

"there is an elliptic curve $E/S$ such that for any other elliptic curve $E'/S'$, a level structure on $E'/S'$ is equivalent to a morphism $S'\rightarrow S$ such that $E'\cong E\times_S S'$."

(after thinking about it for a bit, it seems you can show that $P_N$ representable $\Longrightarrow$ $F_N$ representable)

On the other hand, the functor $F_N$ is much more natural, in that a representing object for $F_N$ much more clearly parametrizes elliptic curves with level structure. However, Peter Bruin's article (http://user.math.uzh.ch/bruin/moduli.pdf) and Katz/Mazur's book (specifically thm's 3.6 and 4.7) both seem to imply that if $P_N$ is not rigid (eg, $N = 1,2$), then even if $F_N$ is representable by an object $M$, the object $M$ might not carry a universal family. I am further confused by the fact that wikipedia (in the section on Fine Moduli Spaces) says that the universal family exists and must correspond to $\text{id}_M\in\text{Hom}(M,M)$.

I'm assuming wikipedia is wrong.

If wikipedia is wrong, then in the case $N = 2$, is the functor $F_2$ representable? If it is, is $\Gamma(2)\backslash\mathcal{H}$ the representing object?

When people talk of the moduli problem of classifying elliptic curves with full level $N$ structure, which functor are they referring to?

...onto stacks...

For $N = 1,2$, there is no fine moduli scheme, and hence at least $P_N$ is not representable. However, is there a fine moduli *stack*? (does that mean anything?)

In general, would I be correct in saying that a stack for a moduli problem is basically just the moduli functor itself? Can you make this more precise? (though I guess you'd have to replace "isomorphism classes of..." with the objects themselves)

Are there *meaningful* moduli problems that aren't stacks?

Thanks for bearing with me

- will

Comment: There's to say here, but let's start with a couple questions.  Something's clearly wrong with your $P_N$ - is $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ supposed to be $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$ or something?  Are you ultimately working over $\mathbb{C}$-schemes here?  This is the only way $\Gamma(N)\backslash\scr{H}$ will be a "moduli scheme" after all.

Comment: Wow, that $H$ came out fancier than I intended.  Let's try $\Gamma(N)\backslash \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Also, the problem $P_N$ (even if fixed up) will not be representable by a modular curve in the sense that you seem to be thinking.  I suspect that you're veering into the realm of a relatively representable moduli problem over the moduli problem classifying elliptic curves, in the sense of Katz-Mazur.  Roughly, what they do is to build up problems like the one you're interested in by first studying the moduli problem for elliptic curves and then consider problems "over" this one and study their relative representability.

Comment: @Ramsey - Yes, I'm referring to the problem of classifying elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$.

And why won't $P_N$ ($N \ge 3$) be representable by a modular curve? (by this I mean, a universal elliptic curve $E$ *over* the appropriate modular curve)

I thought that was the whole point of modular curves..

Comment: On second thought, I think I misspoke.  I didn't quite understand $P_N$ correctly (in particular I missed the bit about the morphisms in $\mathbf{Ell}$ being Cartesian squares).  It seems to me that $P_N$ should be representable iff $F_N$ is.  You've stated one direction.  For the other: suppose that $F_N$ is representable by the $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $X$.  The identity map $X\to X$ gives rise to a universal elliptic curve $E\to X$ which ought to represent $P_N$.

Comment: What Wikipedia is referring to is the necessary existence of a universal family over a fine moduli scheme. Over a coarse moduli scheme, it does not necessarily exist. As far as I know, there is no problem with constructing a fine moduli stack by taking a fine moduli scheme for a larger $N$ and quotienting out by the appropriate group of automorphisms.

Comment: To separate the ideas, for constructing the moduli stack there is almost no content (and no need for higher-level considerations): one just defines the fibered category and checks it satisfies effective descent (which is elementary, since elliptic curves are equipped with a canonical relatively ample line bundle).  It is in the proof that what one has defined is an Artin (or DM) stack that the need for real work appears, namely we have to make a smooth (or etale) scheme cover, and that's how the fine moduli scheme for some larger $N$ enters the picture from the "stack" perspective.

Comment: @oxeimon: Galois deformation theory gives many examples of "functor of isomorphism classes" of objects with automorphisms for which the functor is representable. In those cases the nontrivial automorphisms which occur constitute a smooth functor (e.g., units in the base ring) and hence can be handled in a way which bypasses the non-uniqueness problems one might otherwise expect to encounter when making a proof of representability.  In particular, it is absolutely not true as a matter of mere formalism that "functor of isomorphism classes" cannot be representable in the absence of rigidity.

Comment: cont'd: The K-M proof that representability implies rigidity uses constructions specific to elliptic curves. For example, in char. 0 choose $(E,\alpha) \in F_2(K)$ and let $E'$ be the twist of $E$ by a quadratic extension $L/K$. Quadratic twisting is invisible on 2-torsion (!), so $E'$ has an associated full level-2 structure $\alpha'$. Now $(E,\alpha), (E',\alpha')$ are distinct in $F_2(K)$ (check!) but the same in $F_2(L)$, so $F_2(K) \rightarrow F_2(L)$ is not injective. But $X(k) \rightarrow X(k')$ is injective for any scheme $X$ and field extension $k'/k$, so $F_2$ isn't representable.

Comment: (migrated to a comment since I probably won't expand on it)  What it means to say that $P_N$ is representable is: There is a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $Y$ and an elliptic curve $\mathcal{E}/Y$ equipped with a full level $N$ structure $\mathcal{E}[N]\cong(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$ with the following property: for any elliptic curve $E$ over a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $S$ equipped with a full level $N$ structure, there exists a unique map $S\to Y$ of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes such that $E/S$ with its level structure is isomorphic to the pullback of $\mathcal{E}$ with its level structure along $S\to Y$.

Comment: @Ramsey: I think your comment just above has an error. The definition of representability of $P_N$ asserts the existence and uniqueness of an entire cartesian square (inducing an unspecified isomorphism on the full level-$N$ structures), not just that of a map between the base schemes (lifting to an unspecified isomorphism between elliptic curves equipped with full level-$N$ structure).  What you have written is really expressing the definition of representability of $F_N$. The discrepancy is harmless for $N > 2$, but not by tautology, and for $N \le 2$ it is more serious.

Comment: @quasi-coherent:  Good point.  Suppose I said instead "a unique map $S\to Y$ together with an isomorphism of $E/S$ with the pullback of $\mathcal{E}/Y$ along $S\to Y$"  -  would that be correct then?  

Comment: @Ramsey: Yes, provided it is made clearer that the word "unique" applies to the entire rest of the sentence, whereas as written it looks like it might only apply to the map from $S$ to $Y$ (admitting such a cartesian diagram over it).  So it is clearer and more efficient to say what the category theory formalism says: a unique morphism $(E,S) \rightarrow (\mathcal{E},Y)$ in the category $\mathbf{Ell}$.

Comment: @quasi-coherent:  Agreed on all points.  Thanks for the correction above.  I'll leave all my comments up in case the correction and clarification is helpful to the OP or others.

Comment: @quasi-coherent: Can you explain why a quadratic twist is invisible to 2-torsion? (by this I assume you mean that if all 2-torsion is K-rational on E, then it will remain K-rational on any quadratic twist?)

I can see this explicitly from the fact that all quadratic twists (at least in char 0 for y^2 = f(x)) correspond to dy^2 = f(x) for some non-square d, and hence you can see that the 2-torsion remains unchanged by looking at the inversion formula.

I was wondering if there was a more general, less ad-hoc way to see this.

Comment: @quasi-coherent: Also, as for your second comment regarding $(E,\alpha)$ and $(E',\alpha')$ being distinct in $F_2(K)$, please let me know if I've interpreted this correctly:

Namely, elliptic curves over $K$ are locally given by $K$-algebras $K[x,y]/(y^2-f(x))$, and an isomorphism of elliptic curves over $K$ are just isomorphisms of these $K$-algebras (technically because of properness?). However, these $K$-algebras aren't isomorphic, period, so they must form different isomorphism classes.

Comment: I guess this is one subtle point in viewing elliptic curves as schemes. Ie, usually you view elliptic curves as just the equation and their $\overline{K}$-points, in which case you have to specify fields of definition for morphisms between them. However, when you look at them as schemes, the local "geometric model" $\text{Spec }\overline{K}[x,y]/(y^2-f(x))$ is actually not an elliptic curve over $\text{Spec }K$, since it's not geometrically connected, so you have to look at the $K[x,y]/(y^2-f(x))$ instead, for which morphisms are exactly those defined over $K$ in the usual sense.

Comment: @oxeimon: One should not think about elliptic curves in terms of those affine coordinate rings; best to always think in terms of the proper curve.  Also, when you say that one "usually" views elliptic curves in terms of $\overline{K}$-points...once you learn about schemes, you can and should think entirely in terms of $K$-schemes.  It is much clearer. Mumford's book on abelian varieties, Chapters 2 and 3, gives an excellent presentation of how to use scheme-theoretic methods in both a classical "variety" setting as well as a scheme-theoretic setting (to deal with inseparable isogenies, etc.).

Comment: @oxeimon: One can understand everything without cubic equations (not that it's bad to have the concrete interpretation too). Quadratic twisting is best understood via descent theory, as you'll figure out later in life. In the meantime you can find a discussion in Silverman's first book (e.g., to prove $E' \not\simeq E$). From the descent theory viewpoint one sees that on Tate modules $T_{\ell}(E') = T_{\ell}(E) \otimes \chi$ for the quadratic character $\chi$ for $L/K$, and $\chi$ is invisible on 2-torsion (as negation does nothing there!), so $E'[2] = E[2]$ *canonically* (as Galois modules).

Comment: @oxeimon: For my entire discussion of quadratic twisting I should have imposed the condition on $E$ that the only "geometric" automorphisms of $E$ (i.e., over $\overline{K}$ and not just over $K$) are $\pm 1$.  This condition, which holds whenever $j(E) \ne 0, 1728$, underlies the proof that $E'$ really is not isomorphic to $E$.  (When there are additional automorphisms, such as $\mu_4$, it really can happen that $E$ is isomorphic to one of its quadratic twists; this phenomenon is best understood in terms of Galois cohomology formalism but can also be seen in terms of Weierstrass models.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your $F_N$ is the functor people would usually mean when they talk about the functor classifying elliptic curves with full level N structure (though it's a bit nicer if you replace $(Z/nZ )^2$ with $\mu_n \times Z/nZ$, so that the determinant takes values in $\mu_n$ on both sides.)

Wikipedia is not wrong.  (Wikipedia is surprisingly seldom wrong!)  Your F_2 is indeed not representable by a scheme, which is to say that the scheme known as Y(2) is not a fine moduli space. To say it was a fine moduli space would be precisely to say it represents the functor in question.  That's why Y(2) doesn't have to have a universal family over it.

Yes -- the stack is the same thing as the functor; but we're keeping track of certain facts about that functor when we say it's a stack.  For that matter, in the case where the functor is representable by a scheme, the scheme is *also* the same thing as a functor; but in that case we don't think of it as or refer to it as a functor, because that would make us seem very pretentious.

Comment: I don't think it is quite correct to say "the stack is the same thing as the functor".  Unless I am misreading, the OP is talking about a set-valued functor.  Although often a smooth stack such as this one can be uniquely recovered from a closely related set-valued functor, I think you have to be quite careful how you make that precise.

Comment: Jason is right, of course!  Better to say the stack is the functor to Cat which sends S to the category of pairs (E,alpha)/S, but even then you had better be a bit more careful about what you mean by "functor to Cat." 

Jason is wrong even more seldom than Wikipedia is wrong. 

Comment: +1 for resisting the pretensions of publicly thinking of schemes of functors (it's okay to do it privately).  

Comment: For the benefit of someone trying to improve their understanding of stacks, would you mind saying a tiny bit more about what facts you're tracking when you regard the functor as a stack?